# In what format SMPP protocol data unit (PDU) is sent and received in send and recv socket system call ?

Tags: c, sockets, smpp

Whether the PDU goes in the form of structure or a string ? (In any mode). I am making a C program and want to send a message to a mobile number via SMPP. Either I use a structure or send every PDU content in a single string ?

Comment: What's the question here? The PDU is defined by the SMPP protocol. Structure or string doesn't seem relevant.

Comment: Ok PDU is defined by SMPP.We have header and body fields.But practically if we use send system call,how this PDU will be transferred.What datatype in C will be used to send PDU fields ?

Answer (score 1):

You need to read the SMPP Protocol http://www.turkcell.com.tr/downloads/hakkimizda/pdf/SMPP_v3_4_Issue1_2.pdf. Your question is not as easy as it sounds.

Basically you create a connection to the smpp server using TCP sockets. Then you send packets to login to the smsc server and other packets to send messages.

The packets are called PDUs or Protocol Data Units. Each PDU has a defined set of values that can be there.

The whole protocol is big enough for you to implement it as easy as you are speaking. You will need to rely on a library that abstracts you from the protocol and let you do your messaging in a higher level.

You can google for some smpp C library